# Check if Json field Exist, giving default value with (select) jq command

Tags: json, linux, bash, parsing, jq

I have some JSON data and i want to push some of them to DB , but sometimes the json values not exists for specific devices:
from all of the following data I want just to pull , **"ICCID","MDN","MSISDN","MCC","MNC","FeatureTypes","RatePlanCode","RatePlanDescription","DeviceState","BillingCycleStartDate","BillingCycleEndDate","CurrentBillCycleDataUnRatedUsage"**

and if any one not exist print not-exist .

```
{
"categories": [{
        "categoryName": "DeviceIdentifier",
        "extendedAttributes": [{
                "key": "ICCID",
                "value": "89148000"
            },
            {
                "key": "IMSI",
                "value": "31148094"
            },
            {
                "key": "MDN",
                "value": "5514048068"
            },
            {
                "key": "MEID",
                "value": "A0000000005006"
            },
            {
                "key": "MIN",
                "value": "5514041185"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryName": "DeviceAttributes",
        "extendedAttributes": [{
                "key": "MCC",
                "value": "311"
            },
            {
                "key": "MNC",
                "value": "480"
            },
            {
                "key": "FeatureCodes",
                "value": "75802,84777,54307"
            },
            {
                "key": "FeatureNames",
                "value": "75802,84777,54307"
            },
            {
                "key": "FeatureTypes",
                "value": "4G Public Dynamic"
            },
            {
                "key": "RatePlanCode",
                "value": "4G5G "
            },
            {
                "key": "RatePlanDescription",
                "value": "4G5G"
            },
            {
                "key": "Services",
                "value": "null"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryName": "Provisioning",
        "extendedAttributes": [{
                "key": "LastActivationDate",
                "value": "2022-03-01T19:38:52Z"
            },
            {
                "key": "CreatedAt",
                "value": "2021-12-01T21:22:55Z"
            },
            {
                "key": "DeviceState",
                "value": "active"
            },
            {
                "key": "LastDeactivationDate",
                "value": "2021-12-01T21:22:55Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryName": "Connectivity",
        "extendedAttributes": [{
                "key": "Connected",
                "value": "true"
            },
            {
                "key": "LastConnectionDate",
                "value": "2022-09-08T03:38:55Z"
            },
            {
                "key": "LastDisconnectDate",
                "value": "2022-09-08T03:25:15Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryName": "Billing",
        "extendedAttributes": [{
                "key": "BillingCycleStartDate",
                "value": "2022-09-02T00:00:00Z"
            },
            {
                "key": "BillingCycleEndDate",
                "value": "2022-10-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            {
                "key": "DefaultRatePlan",
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryName": "Usage",
        "extendedAttributes": [{
                "key": "CurrentRatedUsageRecordDate",
                "value": "2022-09-04T00:00:00Z"
            }, {
                "key": "CurrentUnRatedUsageRecordDate",
                "value": "2022-09-08T01:25:15Z"
            },
            {
                "key": "CurrentBillCycleDataUnRatedUsage",
                "value": "1698414605"
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

}

i'm not pushing all fields to db so i'm selecting a specific keys from that,
(**what i'am selecting its fixed not changed**) so the select will not change and always will be :

**Expected output :**

> "89148000"
> "5514048068"
> "not-exist"
> "4G Public Dynamic"
> "4G5G"
> "4G5G"
> "active"
> "2022-09-02T00:00:00Z"
> "2022-10-01T00:00:00Z"
> "2022-09-08T01:25:15Z"

**I would like to check if the value of key is missing for this case "MSISDN" ,if not will print for me not-exist or null**

any help ?

Comment: Does order matter? What should the output be for AAA CCC EEE?

Comment: the input it's fixed , so it's always will be "AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE" , the output its depends on the json filed if exist or not , i updated the post (more explanation)

Comment: Your examples don't really make sense. EEE is missing from the input, CCC is missing from the select filter. Yet, 789 (the value of CCC) should not be printed, yet "NOT-EXISTS"? (but I think my answer even covers that special case, please try it out)

Comment: Do you mean to merge all `extendedAttribute` arrays first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your requirements correctly, but here is a solution that looks simple enough to understand and should be somewhat efficient. If you always expect the same 5 keys in your input, you can try:

```
.categories[].Attributes | from_entries as $attr
  | ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
  | map($attr[.] // "NOT-EXIST")
```

Input:

```json
{"categories": [
{
  "categoryName": "Device",
  "Attributes": [
    {
      "key": "AAA",
      "value": "111"
    },
    {
      "key": "BBB",
      "value": "222"
    },
    {
      "key": "DDD",
      "value": "444"
    },
    {
      "key": "EEE",
      "value": "555"
    }
  ]
}]}
```

Output:

```
[
  "111",
  "222",
  "NOT-EXIST",
  "444",
  "555"
]
```

If you require only the values, add `[]` or `| .[]` at the end of the script or rewrite to:

```
.categories[].Attributes | from_entries as $attr
  | "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"
  | $attr[.] // "NOT-EXIST"
```

---

With the input from updated question, you intend to first merge all `extendedAttributes` array into one big array, convert to an object and then use this complete object to look up your values:

```
.categories | map(.extendedAttributes[]) | from_entries as $attr
  | "ICCID", "MDN", "MSISDN", "MCC", "MNC", "FeatureTypes", "RatePlanCode", "RatePlanDescription", "DeviceState", "BillingCycleStartDate", "BillingCycleEndDate", "CurrentBillCycleDataUnRatedUsage"
  | $attr[.] // "NOT-EXIST"
```

`.categories | map(.extendedAttributes[])` can be rewritten as `[.categories[].extendedAttributes[]]` or `.categories | map(.extendedAttributes) | add`, which might be easier to grok.

Output:

```
"89148000"
"5514048068"
"NOT-EXIST"
"311"
"480"
"4G Public Dynamic"
"4G5G "
"4G5G"
"active"
"2022-09-02T00:00:00Z"
"2022-10-01T00:00:00Z"
"1698414605"
```

---

A version without an intermediate variable is also possible:

```
[
  .categories | map(.extendedAttributes[]) | from_entries[
    "ICCID",
    "MDN",
    "MSISDN",
    "MCC",
    "MNC",
    "FeatureTypes",
    "RatePlanCode",
    "RatePlanDescription",
    "DeviceState",
    "BillingCycleStartDate",
    "BillingCycleEndDate",
    "CurrentBillCycleDataUnRatedUsage"
  ]
]
| map(. // "NOT-EXIST")
```

or

```
[
  .categories | map(.extendedAttributes[]) | from_entries
  | .["ICCID", "MDN", "MSISDN", "MCC", "MNC", "FeatureTypes", "RatePlanCode", "RatePlanDescription", "DeviceState", "BillingCycleStartDate", "BillingCycleEndDate", "CurrentBillCycleDataUnRatedUsage"]
]
| map(. // "NOT-EXIST")
```

Comment: thank you ,it's work fine , but if i have more than 5 keys , it's not working , and already i want to apply it to more than 5 keys ,  on 12 keys , can you help for that please ?

Comment: @Mr.Simple it shouldn't matter how many keys you have. Simply add your keys to the array/to the list of "expected" keys. Can you show an example for which it is not working? Preferrably with more than 5 keys

Comment: i sent to your mail example for that

Comment: @Mr.Simple StackOverflow is not a personal help forum, it's a Q&A site to collect knowledge for _everybody_ to benefit from its content. Please edit your question with additional details if required.

Comment: @Mr.Simple please see my updated answer

Answer (score 4):

```
.categories[].Attributes[] | 
    if (.key | IN(["AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE"][])) 
        then .value 
        else "NOT-EXIST" 
    end
```

Gives the following output

```
"111"
"222"
"NOT-EXIST"
"444"
"555"
```

- First we loop over the `Attributes`
- Then we use an `if` to;

  - Check if `key` exist in `["AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE"]`
  - TRUE: use `.value`
  - FALSE: use `NOT-EXIST` as value

##### [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_A0iCOx17hu)

---

---

Another approach, using `with_entries()` to update the `.value` before looping over all the objects to show just the value, gives the same output as above:

```
.categories[].Attributes[] 
    | select(.key | IN(["AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE"][]) | not).value = "NOT-EXIST"
    | .value
```

##### [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ixibsda1JlE)

Comment: Anything wrong since you un-accepted the answer?

Comment: hi ostone, thanks for your answer 
if the key:"EEE" not in the json fields (not exists) it's not showing that in output
printing not exists just in case if its not in the array ["AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE"] but its exists in json fields ,
what i need the fields are fixed ["AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE"] and if any one from them not exist in json filed will print (not exists)

Comment: I'm not sure what needs to be changed. Could you give an example? If the key does not exist in the array, it will show 'not-exist' as the value

Comment: if the array always be ["AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE"] , 
if the json field : 
{
  "key": "AAA",
  "value": "123"
},
{
  "key": "BBB",
  "value": "456"
},
{
  "key": "DDD",
  "value": "098"
},
{
  "key": "EEE",
  "value": "555"
} 
the output for that : "123" "456" "098" "555"
-----------------------
if the json field : 
{
  "key": "AAA",
  "value": "123"
},
{
  "key": "BBB",
  "value": "456"
},
{
  "key": "DDD",
  "value": "098"
}
the output for that will be : "123" "456" "098" "NOT-EXISTS"

Comment: `IN([.....][])` can (and perhaps ought to) be simplified to: `IN(.....)`

Comment: i updated the post (more explanation)